# How to parse two similar string to datetime in one formatter with joda?

Tags: java, jodatime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

Now I have two different formats of date written in string:

```
String date1 = "2018-10-12 18:01:01";// yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
String date2 = "2018-10-12 18:01";//yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
```

I am using `joda` and I want to convert the string to `DateTime`,the basic way is to use two formatter to parse each of them:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
DateTime dt1 = formatter1.parseDateTime(date1);
DateTime dt2 = formatter2.parseDateTime(date2);
```

Above code blocks works fine but it created two formatter,since the date formate is very similar(the latter one just lack of seconds),I am wonder if there is a way that I can just use one formatter to parse all of them or I have to use two formatter?

Note: 
**due to the production enviroment limit,I can not use `java8` now,so I want to the answer based on `joda`**

Thanks in advance!

---

I just tried as below,and got `IllegalArgumentException： Invalid format`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt1 = formatter.parseDateTime(date1);
DateTime dt2 = formatter.parseDateTime(date2);
```

Comment: you can prob preprocess all `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` dates, i.e. append `:00` to them, if you can't find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API through the ThreeTen Backport library.
2. Use Joda-Time as you are already doing.

### ThreeTen Backport

Two quotes from the Joda-Time home page:

> Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).
>
> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
>   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
>   to `java.time` (JSR-310).

The good news is you can migrate even if using Java 6 or 7. The developers of java.time (lead by Stephen Colebourne, also the lead developer of Joda-Time) have also developed the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of java.time for Java 6 and 7. See the link at the bottom.

Anton Balaniuc is already showing the code in his good answer, so there’s no use for me to repeat that here.

### Joda-Time

```
    String date1 = "2018-10-12 18:01:01";// yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
    String date2 = "2018-10-12 18:01";//yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
    DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
                    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormat.forPattern(":ss").getParser())
                    .toFormatter();
    DateTime dt1 = parser.parseDateTime(date1);
    DateTime dt2 = parser.parseDateTime(date2);
    System.out.println("dt1: " + dt1);
    System.out.println("dt2: " + dt2);
```

On my computer in Europe/Copenhagen time zone the output from this snippet was:

```
dt1: 2018-10-12T18:01:01.000+02:00
dt2: 2018-10-12T18:01:00.000+02:00
```

As you can see, the key to specifying optional parts in the format is the `appendOptional` method of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

### Links

- [Joda-Time home page](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- [Answer by Anton Balaniuc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52778567/5772882) showing the code for java.time
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can indicate that some parts of the format are optional using `[]`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm[:ss]");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-10-12 18:01:01", formatter);
LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-10-12 18:01", formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime + " " + dateTime1);
```

result is

```
2018-10-12T18:01:01 2018-10-12T18:01
```

Please see [Patterns for Formatting and Parsing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) section for more info.

Comment: it's a bit annoying it's parsed as 01 though, should it not be 18:01:00

Comment: @gherkin it is actually `18:01:00`, if you do `dateTime1.getSecond()` returns `0`, probably it is just `DateTime.toString` issue, since it uses `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm[:ss]` format

Comment: @gherkin, yep it is a formatter issue, if I use different formatter ` System.out.println(dateTime + " " + dateTime1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));`  it outputs as `18:01:00`

Comment: When I tested in my side,I got the error `Invalid format: "2018-10-10 10:10:12" is malformed at ":12"`,I am using `java8` and `joda2.4` test it

Comment: @lucumt, it is LocalDateTime from `java.time` package, the jdk class not an external one. I am afraid I don't know how to do it with `joda.time`

Comment: Because due to my environment limit I can not use `java8`,thus I have to use `joda` to do it

Comment: Oh, you can use the java.time API on Java 6 and 7 too, there’s a backport: [the ThreeTen Backport library](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` class, something like this.

```
  private DateTimeFormatter formatterBuilder() {
        return new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
                .optionalStart().appendPattern(":ss").optionalEnd()
                .toFormatter();
    }
```

Comment: Seems your solution is based on `java8`,I tested on `joda2.4` it do not have method called `optionalStart()`